# Is there a difference between conjuncted condition and multiple Where method call?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I was sitting this cloudy Saturday morning thinking to myself:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType>
  someThings = ...,
  conjunctedThings = someThings.Where(thing => thing.Big && thing.Tall),
  multiWhereThings = someThings
    .Where(thing => thing.Big).Where(thing => thing.Tall);
```

Intuitively, I'd say that *conjunctedThings* will be computed no slower than *multiWhereThings* but is there really a difference in a general case?

I can imagine that depending on the share if big things and tall tings, the computations might elapse differently but I'd like to disregard that aspect.

Are there any other properties I need to take into consideration? E.g. the type of the enumerable or anything else?

Comment: It depends on _"..."_ really. For example take a look at Entity Framework. Whether you do one `Where` with all conditions or a `Where` per condition, when calling the enumerator, all `Where`'s will be compacted into a single SQL WHERE.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. Care to draw some lines around the dependencies, other than those I mentioned?

Comment: "Conjuncted" (awesome word btw) `Where` and `Select` queries are optimized by LINQ to Objects. Your best bet any time you have a performance question is **get out a stopwatch and try it both ways**. Then you'll know. Any answers you get here are speculation. There's no substitute for measurement when you have a performance question.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for putting my thoughts in better words and for your [horse racing](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) argument.

Comment: @EricLippert Checking the real case would be perfect. The problem is that I've got no info on the contents of the array to be filtered, accept that it's going to be filtered with respect to two boolean properties. I was hoping that there's a known optimization (or at least a general concensus what to do) when putting *Where* conjunctedly (even awesomer wording, haha). Based on the response, I'm concluding that such doesn't exist and if the code I deliver will pose an issue, I can **then** try the other one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the MultiWhere will be slower. It needs to process more items and call more lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

If `someThings` contains `n` items, and `m` of which are `Big` then the lambda for conjucated-things is called `n` times while the lambdas for multi-where are called `n+m` times. Of couse this is true if the user of the two sequences intends to iterate *all* the contents. Since the `Where` method performs `yield return` internally the number of iterations might be less depending on the user of the collections. In other words the numbers above are the worst-case estimate.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Let me just point out that this particular consideration is already included in my question (although I can admit that it might be put more clearly). The share of bigs and talls affect, apparently, just like you say. What more?